# Evaluate $\int_{-7}^{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{9 - 3x }} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

The problem below looks like this but I'm not sure if I did the problem correctly, I just learned this and I haven't taken math in a few years...

$$\int_{-7}^{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{9 - 3x }} \,dx$$

$$u=9-3x 
\qquad du=-3\,dx$$

I applied the power rule and ended up with this as an answer, would this be correct, if not, how do I get the correct answer?

$$\frac{2}{3} ({\sqrt{30}}- {\sqrt{3}})$$

Thank you!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, since $9 - 3(x + 3) = \sqrt{-3x}$, translate both the integrand and the bounds of integration $3$ units left to get:

$$I = \int_{-10}^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{-3x}} \ dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{-3} \left[ \frac{(-3x)^{1/2}}{1/2} \right]_{-10}^{-1} \tag{reverse chain rule}$$
$$=\frac{1}{-3} \cdot 2 (\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{30}) $$
$$=\frac{2}{3} (\sqrt{30} - \sqrt{3}). $$

Answer (score 2):

This answer is correct; not much to really nitpick here.

---

*Posting as Community Wiki since I don't really have anything to add, but don't wish for this to end up in the unanswered question queue.*

Answer (score 0):

You can always eliminate *one* linear term in x (here: 9-3x).

First you replace 3x with x by making all the x three times larger (integral from -21 to +6), but since this makes the area of the integral 3 times wider, you divide the result by 3.

Now the values 9-x vary from 30 to 3. So you replace 9-x with x and the integral with 3 to 30 and get the same result.

Comment: I have the spirit of your approach.